# Is there anyway to name the columns of dataframe by using pipeline operator?

Tags: r, tidyverse, pipeline

Sample dataset is as below:

```
a = data.frame(c(1:3), c(4:6))

#a %>% `names <-` ('w', 'q')
#The code did not work...
```

If I want to rename the columns as 'w' and 'q', what should I do to get the result by using pipeline operator instead of names(a) = c('w', 'q')?

Comment: `a %>% rename(w = 1, q = 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace all the names, you can use `setNames`:

```r
a <- data.frame(x = c(1:3), y = c(4:6))

a %>%
  setNames(c('w', 'q'))
#>   w q
#> 1 1 4
#> 2 2 5
#> 3 3 6
```

This also works with the base R pipe operator `|>`.

If you want to replace just one or two you can use `rename` from `dplyr` (which I assume you already have loaded given that you are using `%>%`):

```r
a %>%
  rename(z = 2)
#>   x z
#> 1 1 4
#> 2 2 5
#> 3 3 6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there anyway to do something like: names(a)[2] = 'q'?